# Paste from Word, Still Bringing Over Custom Formatting

Tags: content-editor

We have an internal editorial process which requires team members to make text updates in Microsoft Word before posting in Sitecore. We've tried all of the different pasting options from the Rich Text Editor and we have not found a process that strips out all of the additional Word formatting. This leads us to incorrect fonts and styles being applied to text when we enter the content.

Our team has to then go into the HTML to manually adjust the formatting before publishing. is there an add-on or process that can successfully remove all the custom word formatting, but keep the basic formatting in tact (bullets, bold, underline etc.)?

Right now we have to paste the text into notepad and then paste the text into the editor to manually adjust all formatting. This is a very cumbersome process.

Why have other CMS systems (i.e. Wordpress) been able to figure this out, but still have challenges within Sitecore?

Comment: ctrl+sfift+V  inserts text without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you probably can try to play with your Telerik control paste settings configuration like described here: https://blog.boro2g.co.uk/paste-into-sitecore-rich-text-editor-from-word-and-remove-styling/.

UPD: to make sure the answer stays here if that link goes down I'm rephrasing what's suggested:
If you open `\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx` there is following node:

```
<telerik:radeditor  ID="Editor" runat="server"
    <...>
    StripFormattingOnPaste="MSWordRemoveAll,ConvertWordLists"
    <...> />
```

You may try replacing MSWordRemoveAll,ConvertWordLists with other possible options that telerik describes here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx(it seems that you can try enabling them directly at that page too to check whether it works as required) and see if that works better for your usecase.

Comment: Hi Elena, this is a link only answer. To better serve this community, can you please add a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you @GauravAgarwal I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

To paste content from Word into a Rich Text field:

In Word, select and copy all the text that you want to paste into a Rich Text field in Sitecore.

In Sitecore, navigate to the item that you want to edit and do one of the following:-

- From the Content Editor – In the content area, locate the Rich Text field that you want to edit and click Show editor.
- From the Experience Editor – click the Rich Text field that you want to edit and in the floating toolbar, click Edit text.

Click Paste Word to insert the text into the Rich Text Editor.

When you are finished editing in the Rich Text Editor, click Accept to save your changes.